# Stop macro expansion of bool

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

Implementing functions through macros is a nightmare with bool. I've defined macros for the head and body of a (generic) function. When using bool type, results are weird.

I get that this is the kind of stuff you generally want to avoid for maintainability ~ but in my case it's a collection of really similar callback functions and a really harsh abbreviation.

So the goals are actually maintainability and readability, especially code coherence.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FUN_H(TYPE) \
  void fun_##TYPE( void )

#define FUN(TYPE) \
  FUN_H(TYPE) { \
    printf("Type is " #TYPE ".\n"); \
  }

FUN_H(int);
FUN_H(bool);

FUN(int);
FUN(bool);

int main(void) {
  fun_int();
  fun_bool();
}
```

Reading the code, I would expect the output "Type is int." and "Type is bool."

Actually, to make the code compile (current gcc/clang) last call must be changed to `fun__Bool();` and the header to `FUN_H(_Bool);` -- which actually makes sense if you know your C99, but produces incoherent code.

---

## Possible solutions

### Use `_Bool` type directly

```c
FUN_H(_Bool);
FUN(_Bool); // or FUN(bool);

int main(void) {
  fun__Bool();
}
```

#### PROs

- no footprint

#### CONs

- ugly!
- two ways to do define the same function, but printing different outputs

---

### Manually expand `FUN()` macro

```c
#define FUN(TYPE) \
  void fun_##TYPE( void ) { \
    printf("Type is " #TYPE ".\n"); \
  }
```

#### PROs

- general solution for other macro'ed types

#### CONs

- not DRY compliant

---

### `typedef` for `_Bool`

```c
typedef _Bool mybool;

FUN_H(mybool);
FUN(mybool);

int main(void) {
  fun_mybool();
}
```

#### PROs

- conservative

#### CONs

- special type name needed

---

### Change `bool` into a `typedef`

```c
#undef bool
typedef _Bool bool;

FUN_H(bool);
FUN(bool);

int main(void) {
  fun_bool();
}
```

#### PROs

- clean

#### CONs

- might break something arcane

---

So what **should** I do?

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the `FUN_H` macro?   By that I mean, what do you see as an advantage of `FUN_H(int); FUN_H(bool)` over `void fun_int(); void fun_bool()`.  While I can understand the purpose of the `FUN` macro (defining functions in a way that reduces typing) the `FUN_H` macro doesn't do that.

Comment: "So the goals are actually maintainability and readability" Then drop these ugly macros ASAP. You are making the code unreadable and unmaintainable. The problem is with the macros themselves - you should not invent a new syntax for how to declare functions. C programmers _know_ how functions are declared. However, they don't know your secret macro language. So what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Type-generic function interface? Function overloading a la C++?

Comment: @Peter The actual function has a (much) longer list of parameters required by a certain library. `FUN_H` is to be put in the header file to keep declaration and definition parameter lists in sync from a central source, i.e. for library changes

Comment: @Lundin This is the interface between a library treating values as that lib's "Variant" datatype and a key-value store. As you may imagine, fetching a value and converting it to its "Variant" representation depending on its type is rather repetitive. Rest assured though, the actual macro content is minimized and fully unit-tested.

Comment: It would probably be easier in that case to write a little program that generates the header (function declarations) and source (function definitions) directly from the "central source", rather than resorting to macros.     Also, DRY is a guideline to avoid *unnecessary* repetition.   It is not a guideline to eliminate repetition by making code unreadable.   If it was a prohibition, it would not be acceptable to write more than one `for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)` loop across any sections of related code, which would just be absurd.

Comment: @Peter I understand. However, we already have had issues with not keeping the headers of these functions in sync, hence the existence of the macros. Generator program seems like a good idea -- but not before the next refinement iteration.

Comment: @miehe-dup The best solution then is to enforce coding standards, perhaps check the code with static analysis. No macros in the world will save you from crazy programmers writing code aimlessly. But if you _must_ use macros because the code is already a mess, then consider using "X macros" to centralize everything at one single place.

Comment: That is, aren't you rather looking for something like this? https://godbolt.org/z/8Jbotu Just a silly example but you get the idea.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not sure if that's awful or awesome. Anyway, thanks for sharing, I've never seen a MWE of that technique!

Comment: @Lundin How would one expose `fun(param)` in a header?

Comment: @miehe-dup What do you mean? In a real project, everything but the function definition would be in header files. It is common that the X macro list (FUNCTION_LIST in that example) is placed in a header of its own, since it is the only part you'd maintain. Anyway, it is pretty hard to discuss best design practices when only using these artificial examples.

Comment: @Lundin Of course d'oh. Not sure how I missed that yesterday ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned, passing `TYPE` to any intermediate macro will force its expansion before further processing. So the concatenation must happen as early as possible, before passing `TYPE` anywhere. To achieve it without repeating ourselves too much, we can just delegate to a third macro

```
#define FUN_H(TYPE) \
  FUN_H_(fun_##TYPE)

#define FUN_H_(NAME) \
  void NAME( void )

#define FUN(TYPE) \
  FUN_H_(fun_##TYPE) { \
    printf("Type is " #TYPE ".\n"); \
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

It's the inner `FUN_H` macro call that expands `bool` to `_Bool` if `bool` is a macro. If you lose the inner `FUN_H` macro and write `FUN` directly like so:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define FUN_H(TYPE) \
  void fun_##TYPE( void )

#define FUN(TYPE) \
  void fun_##TYPE( void ) { \
    printf("Type is " #TYPE ".\n"); \
  }

FUN_H(int);
FUN_H(bool);

FUN(int);
FUN(bool);

int main(void) {
  fun_int();
  fun_bool();
}
```

then you'll get `fun_bool` as expected, even if `bool` is a macro.

Comment: Yes, it works, but that partly defeats the purpose of `FUN_H` macro and doesn't look "DRY" ...

Comment: @miehe-dup - Then pass `NAME` instead of `TYPE` to `FUN_H`. Do the concatenation on the caller side. That way only the smallest bit that has to be repeated will be repeated.

Comment: @StoryTeller I've updated my Q with possible solutions. There is no `NAME` (yet), I'm not sure if I'm getting you right. Could you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

Any way around, the dynamic you have to deal with is that the preprocessor operates by a sequence of (re)scan / full-expand operations.  Macro names appearing in the expansion of a macro **M** are themselves expanded only in the context of rescanning the full expansion of **M**, including the expansions of all its parameters and / or the applications of its token-pastings and stringifications, as appropriate.

Thus, if a macro argument is the name of an object-like macro then it cannot be passed as itself as the argument to another macro -- if you attempt to do so, then it will be that macro's expansion that gets passed.  The problem here is more typically how to ensure that that happens in the face of stringification or token-pasting, so your issue is a bit unusual in wanting to do the reverse.

You've already raised a lot of working alternatives with which you seem unsatisfied, but here's one that has all the advantages you've so-far discussed, and none of the disadvantages: define an additional macro that patches up the unwanted expansion.  For example,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

// This macro corrects the unwanted expansion to the wanted one:
#define fun__Bool fun_bool

// The rest of the code is identical to your initial, non-working example

#define FUN_H(TYPE) \
  void fun_##TYPE( void )

#define FUN(TYPE) \
  FUN_H(TYPE) { \
    printf("Type is " #TYPE ".\n"); \
  }

FUN_H(int);
FUN_H(bool);

FUN(int);
FUN(bool);

int main(void) {
  fun_int();
  fun_bool();
}
```

Alternatively, you could instead introduce a macro that swaps function identifiers the other way around, so that it is *calls* that get changed, not declarations.

I think there are other alternatives that would allow you to use the original style of your example, but all such approaches I've considered so far are messier and more brittle.